# How to use Multiple yajra datatables with parameters?

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

Please see the code

```
public function admin_dashboard(TableOneDataTable $dataTable1,TableTwoDataTable $dataTable2)
    {
        $from = $to = date('Y-m-d');
        
        $dataTable1 = $dataTable1->with(['from' => $from, 'to' => $to])->html();
        $dataTable2 = $dataTable2->with(['from' => $from, 'to' => $to])->html();
        return view('operation.admin_dashboard',compact('from','to','dataTable1','dataTable2'));
    }

public function get_datatable1(TableOneDataTable $dataTable1)
    {
        return $dataTable1->render('operation.admin_dashboard');
    }
public function get_datatable2(TableTwoDataTable $dataTable2)
    {
        return $dataTable2->render('operation.admin_dashboard');
    }
//in route 
Route::get('/get_datatable1', 'BillingDepartmentController@get_datatable1');
Route::get('/get_datatable2', 'BillingDepartmentController@get_datatable2');
//in datatble
public function query(OperationAssignment $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery()
            ->with('created_user:id,first_name,last_name','updated_user:id,first_name,last_name')
            ->where('date','>=',$this->from)
            ->where('date','<=',$this->to);
    }
->minifiedAjax('/get_datatable1')
```

I want to use both datatable in same page. Also pass the parameter in the datatble. I can not use parameter when I use this.

Comment: This seems to just be a repost of your previous question? [How to use Multiple yajra datatable with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76432964/how-to-use-multiple-yajra-datatable-with-parameters)

Comment: Yes but now, this post get an answer. So the duplicate will be accepted to a worst post

Answer (score 0):

Datatable arguments are key value pair.
try this

```
$dataTable1 = $dataTable1->with('from',$from)->with'(to' => $to)->html();
$dataTable2 = $dataTable2->with('from',$from)->with'(to' => $to)->html();
```

instead of this

```
$dataTable1 = $dataTable1->with(['from' => $from, 'to' => $to])->html();
$dataTable2 = $dataTable2->with(['from' => $from, 'to' => $to])->html();
```

then access the arguments in the Datatable class

```
$this->from and $this->to
```